# Implementando escuchar un botón en el adaptador

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito capturar el evento click en un boton para mostrar la factura que se encuentra en esa porcion del reciclyerView. Este es el activitity:

```
Adapter_Empresa_Vs_Pedidos adapter = new Adapter_Empresa_Vs_Pedidos(itemList, new ClickListener(){
                                @Override public void onPositionClicked(int v) {
                                    NroFac= itemList.get(v).getCodFac();
                                    Intent i = new Intent(List_Pedidos_vs_Empresa_RecyclerView.this, List_Aceptar_Pedido.class);
                                    i.putExtra("NroFac",NroFac);
                                }
                                @Override public void onLongClicked(int position) {
                                    // callback performed on click
                                }
                            });
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Pero cuando paso por el adaptador que es este
me da un error en el **R.layout.item_rv_empresa_pedidos** (lo coloque asi para resaltarlo). Me dice el error que no puede resolver el metodo inflate(int). y ahi quedo loco ya tengo varias dias tratando de cambiar pero no cual es el error.

```
public class Adapter_Empresa_Vs_Pedidos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_Empresa_Vs_Pedidos.MyViewHolder> {
    private final List<Lst_Emp_vs_Pedidos> itemList;
    private final ClickListener listener;


    public Adapter_Empresa_Vs_Pedidos(List<Lst_Emp_vs_Pedidos> itemList, ClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return  MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(**R.layout.item_rv_empresa_pedidos**),parent, listener);



    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Lst_Emp_vs_Pedidos item = itemList.get(position);
        holder.TvValor.setText( "Valor: " + item.getValor_Total());
        holder.TvPedido.setText( "Pedido Nro." +item.getCodFac());
        holder.TvCelCli.setText( item.getId_celular());
        holder.TvDirCli.setText( item.getId_direccion());
        holder.TvNomCli.setText( item.getUser_nom());

    }

    public int getItemCount() { return itemList.size(); }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        private Button btnButon;
        private TextView TvValor;
        private TextView TvPedido;
        private TextView TvCelCli;
        private TextView TvDirCli;
        private TextView TvNomCli;
        private WeakReference<ClickListener> listenerRef;


        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView, ClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            listenerRef = new WeakReference<>(listener);
            TvNomCli = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNomCliente);
            TvDirCli = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDireccion);
            TvCelCli = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCelular);
            TvPedido = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNroPedido);
            TvValor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvValorPed);
            btnButon = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnVerPedidoEmp);
            btnButon.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El motivo es que no estás invocando correctamente el método inflate:
[image: Android inflate methods]

El primero de ellos necesita un resource y un root.  El caso es que te has equivocado porque te falta un paréntesis.  Lo mejor es crear variables que facilitan la lectura, de esta manera lo resolverás:

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_empresa_pedido, parent)
return MyViewHolder(view, listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias Manuel Mato me diste una luz y así lo pude solucionar para aquellos que han tenido el mismo error y se han reventado la cabeza les dejo como lo pude solucionar.

```
@Override public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_empresa_pedidos, parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view, listener);
 }
```